# I need to paginate results in django using hundreds of thousands of rows without running the query again

Tags: python, html, sql, django, postgresql-9.1

I need to paginate a very large result (300,000 rows) but I don't want to run the query again. Is there a way to make two search(request): the first one to give me the list with the data, and the second result(request): to post the queried data from the first request. I'm trying to do this so I don't have to run the query again and again after displaying every page. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Not really, but I don't know why you'd want to. Paginating a query will only fetch the elements you want from the database on each request; what you're asking would make things *less* efficient, not more.

Comment: use endless pagination. what you are asking is not a good solution http://django-endless-pagination.readthedocs.io/en/latest/start.html

Comment: The problem is that I am using a raw sql query that fetches data out of the database which has about 10 billion rows. The quesryset is turned from a tuple and then to a list, which is then, edited and converted. The list is then paginated and posted. This process takes long for queries that contain over 10,000 rows, so what I am looking to do is to save the query set that is edited, and then paginate it using a different httprequest method, and post it to the webpage.